# Simple Query with SQL injection protection takes magnitudes longer than without

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlperformance, oracle19c

I'm very inexperienced on Oracle. What's going on here?

Query A:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM MUHSCHEMA.MUH_TABLE
 WHERE MUH_DATE = TO_DATE(
                          TRIM(
                            '''' FROM SYS.DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_LITERAL('09/30/2020')), 
                            'mm/dd/yyyy'
                          );
```

Query B:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM MUHSCHEMA.MUH_TABLE
 WHERE MUH_DATE = TO_DATE('09/30/2020', 'mm/dd/yyyy');
```

Query A takes ~22 minutes. Query B takes ~28 seconds. And, seemingly, both of the `TO_DATE` calls with or without the `ENQUOTE_LITERAL` return the same thing.

Why is Query A taking so long?

Query A Plan:

```
| Id  | Operation                 | Name                     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT          |                          |     1 |     9 |   411K  (2)| 00:00:17 |       |       |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE           |                          |     1 |     9 |            |          |       |       |
|   2 |   VIEW                    | A_TABLE                  |    71M|   610M|   411K  (2)| 00:00:17 |       |       |
|   3 |    UNION-ALL              |                          |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|   4 |     PARTITION RANGE ALL   |                          |    28M|   214M| 42669  (15)| 00:00:02 |     1 |1048575|
|   5 |      PARTITION LIST ALL   |                          |    28M|   214M| 42669  (15)| 00:00:02 |     1 |    25 |
|*  6 |       INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| A_TABLE.                 |    28M|   214M| 42669  (15)| 00:00:02 |     1 |1048575|
|   7 |     PARTITION RANGE ALL   |                          |    42M|   327M|   368K  (1)| 00:00:15 |     1 |1048575|
|   8 |      PARTITION LIST ALL   |                          |    42M|   327M|   368K  (1)| 00:00:15 |     1 |    25 |
|*  9 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN    | A_TABLE.                 |    42M|   327M|   368K  (1)| 00:00:15 |     1 |1048575|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

"   6 - filter(""MUH_DATE""=TO_DATE(TRIM('''' FROM ""DBMS_ASSERT"".""ENQUOTE_LITERAL""('09/30/2020')),'mm/dd/yy"
              yy'))
"   9 - access(""MUH_DATE""=TO_DATE(TRIM('''' FROM ""DBMS_ASSERT"".""ENQUOTE_LITERAL""('09/30/2020')),'mm/dd/yy"
              yy'))
```

Query B Plan:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                 | Name                     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT          |                          |     1 |     9 | 36612   (1)| 00:00:02 |       |       |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE           |                          |     1 |     9 |            |          |       |       |
|   2 |   VIEW                    | A_TABLE.                 |    28M|   241M| 36612   (1)| 00:00:02 |       |       |
|   3 |    UNION-ALL              |                          |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|   4 |     PARTITION RANGE SINGLE|                          |    28M|   214M| 36608   (1)| 00:00:02 |   250 |   250 |
|   5 |      PARTITION LIST ALL   |                          |    28M|   214M| 36608   (1)| 00:00:02 |     1 |    25 |
|*  6 |       INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| A_TABLE                  |    28M|   214M| 36608   (1)| 00:00:02 |  6226 |  6250 |
|   7 |     PARTITION RANGE SINGLE|                          |     1 |     8 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |    93 |    93 |
|   8 |      PARTITION LIST ALL   |                          |     1 |     8 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |     1 |    25 |
|*  9 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN    | A_TABLE.                 |     1 |     8 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |  2301 |  2325 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

"   6 - filter(""MUH_DATE""=TO_DATE(' 2020-09-30 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))"
"   9 - access(""MUH_DATE""=TO_DATE(' 2020-09-30 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))"
```

Comment: As an aside, and you're probably already aware, but this isn't the best way to protect this type of query from SQL injection - you would typically use bind variables instead, which has additional benefits (reduced parsing of the query, not flooding the SGA with similar queries,, etc)

Comment: It looks rather like `enquote_literal` and conversion to a date is being repeated for every row in the table; I can replicate the effect on a large (non-partitioned) table with an unindexed date column - adding an index seems to cure it, and would speed up the 28s version too. Or you could convert the value once in a materialized CTE but that seems  a bit messy. As Boneist said, it would be better to pass in a bound value that is already a date if possible.

Comment: Execution plans are above... though, I don't know why what seemingly generates the same value produces two different execution plans?

Understood on the bind variables... just getting something working now.

However, this still doesn't answer the question. Does Oracle want to re-evaluate the calls with DBMS_ASSERT for every record because it's relying on a non-builtin?

Comment: The part I don't understand is why you expect SQL injection to be possible through hard-coded literals in your query. Are you, in fact, using substitution variables in that place? If you are, Oracle has no way of knowing that the value at runtime will be the same in every row (SQL doesn't understand the SQL\*Plus scripting language, and even if it did, your query should use the `&&` notation to show that the variable gets the same literal value everywhere). What I am saying is this: If that is your exact query, then why are you doing it that way? And if it's different, show us the real one.

Comment: @mathguy the value '09/30/2020' comes from a web request...  https://www.oracle.com/assets/how-to-write-injection-proof-plsql-1-129572.pdf

Comment: OK, but how is it passed to the query? It seems it's not hard-coded then (unlike the query you posted, where it is hard-coded). Are you using substitution variables? Then SQL injection is possible, and you need to use DBMS_ASSERT, etc. But you should not pass it through a substitution variable; as has been pointed out already, you should use bind variables instead. If you are new to SQL and don't quite understand what these are, or the distinction between them, Google is your friend - read about "bind variables" and how they are used for your situation.

Comment: We're not talking about building queries at this point.... we're talking about how oracle translates what seems to be two similar queries into two radically different implementations.

Comment: @AlexPoole I guess I'm more confused by the fact that an index cures it...

Comment: @steamrolla - me too... my guess would be that with no index it always does a full table scan, with one it assesses the date earlier to decide if it can do an index full scan or range scan. Something similar could be happening with partition pruning in your example. Not sure that really makes sense though; except now the plan has an access predicate, not a filter predicate - so maybe those are being evaluated differently. (Though still kind of sounds like a bug, so might be worth asking Oracle.)

Comment: Seems to change at “partition range all” and “partition range single”. This would indicate that trim..enquote prevents the QP from understanding/applying pruning — https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-E677C85E-C5E3-4927-B3DF-684007A7B05D.htm

Comment: @user2864740 The only answer doesn't explain the performance problem caused by a lack of partition pruning. Your comment deserves to be at the top but since it cannot, you should create answer. I'll probably upvote it and then delete this comment.

Comment: Looks like the function that is compared to your partitioning column has to be deterministic so its value is known at hard parse time for you to get partition pruning: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2143468000346279561 Not sure if your query A TO_DATE function is deterministic or not. The optimizer seems to think not.

Comment: You might try changing your `muh_date = to_date(...)` to  `muh_date = (select to_date(...) from dual)` to get some scalar subquery caching.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson yea, I tried that... produces the same result as not wrapping it in `(SELECT ... FROM DUAL)`

Answer (score 0):

> the value '09/30/2020' comes from a web request

Then whatever is handling the web request will almost certainly support parametrized queries and bind variables. Don't try to build the query using string concatenation and then use `DBMS_ASSERT` to try to prevent SQL injection, just use a bind variable.

An anonymous bind variable typically has the `?` placeholder (but you should check the syntax for whatever service is handling the web requests):

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM   MUHSCHEMA.MUH_TABLE
WHERE  MUH_DATE = TO_DATE( ?, 'mm/dd/yyyy');
```

Or named bind variables are usually prefixed with `:`, like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM   MUHSCHEMA.MUH_TABLE
WHERE  MUH_DATE = TO_DATE( :variable_name, 'mm/dd/yyyy');
```

Even better, if you can convert the string to a date in whatever is handling the web request then you can pass the date value to the bind variable and do not need to use `TO_DATE`:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM   MUHSCHEMA.MUH_TABLE
WHERE  MUH_DATE = :date_variable_name;
```

> we're talking about how oracle translates what seems to be two similar queries into two radically different implementations.

If one is doing a full table scan and trying to use `DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_LITERAL` on every row then it will take a lot of time to repeatedly do that. The solution could be to use an index but the better solution is to not use `DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_LITERAL` at all and to pass the value into the query as a `DATE` data type via a bind variable.

The [How to write SQL injection proof PL/SQL](https://www.oracle.com/assets/how-to-write-injection-proof-plsql-1-129572.pdf) document you reference in comments states on page 31:

> Rule 6: Use   compile-time-fixed   SQL   statement   text   unless   you   cannot.

Bind variables let you use compile-time-fixed SQL statements; regardless of what the variable's value is the statement does not need to change and you can be sure that the query is not vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: What's hilarious is I've gone to bind variables with https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb ... and I get the same performance as the DBMS_ASSERT query. Furthermore, adding an index doesn't answer the question why oracle wants to re-evaluate what I was thinking would be evaluated once before any table scan started... also, I have no control over the DB and how it is maintained :(